# laravel carbon wherebetween date not working properly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon, week-number

What I want is to be able to get the records from a week number. But when I use the first query nothing is returned. The second query returns the records from the same week but with the carbon in the query and then it works.

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$date->setISODate(2020,20);
return Timesheet::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->whereBetween('date', array($date->startOfWeek(), $date->endOfWeek()))->get();
```

Output:

```
[]
```

```
return Timesheet::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get();
```

Output:

```
[{"id":3,"user_id":1,"project_id":1,"start_time":"2020-05-17 10:58:25","end_time":"2020-05-17 13:58:25","date":"2020-05-16","description":"text","created_at":"2020-05-17T14:58:25.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-05-17T14:58:25.000000Z"}]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what date does `$date` end up as after your `setISODate` call?

Comment: it's exactly the same as the carbon::now()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course  the result will be [].

back to your first between:

```
Timesheet::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
->whereBetween('date', array($date->startOfWeek(), $date->endOfWeek()))->get();
```

please consider this:

```
$date->startOfWeek();
```

this line is equivalent to:

```
$date=$date->startOfWeek();
```

so: the variable '$date' at the end will hold one value, witch is the end of the week and whereBetween will be between the same value!

to avoid this you could use:

```
Timesheet::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->whereBetween('date', array( 
Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(),
Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()))
->get();
```

or:

```
$weekStart=Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
$weekEnd=Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
Timesheet::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->whereBetween('date', array( 
    $weekStart,
    $weekEnd))
    ->get();
```

please note if you want to add date to a variable from Carbon type without change your variable value you could use Carbon::make() method:

```
$value=Carbon::now();
$afterThreeDaysFromValue=Carbon::make($value)->addDays(3);
```

Comment: Just be warned Carbon::now() change at every call, so you might get 2020-05-31 23:59:59.999871 (startOfWeek = 2020-05-25 00:00), then few milliseconds after, the week is over: 2020-06-01 00:00:00.000103 (endOfWeek = 2020-06-07 23:59) and you get a 2 week range, so I recommend $date->copy() instead.